# how to save a file as read only using file download dialog

Tags: c#, file

How to save a file as read only using file download dialog in c#.net.
I have to pick a file in temp folder and save it using file download dialog as read only

Comment: Is this an ASP.NET application, or a desktop application that is downloading the file from a website, then storing it locally?

Comment: Yes , it is a web application, it will be stored in temp folder and then retrieved from temp folder

Comment: Completely unclear. According to your answer, a web application is downloading a file from a website (i.e. another web application) and wants to save a file using a file download dialog. This makes no sense.

Comment: Hi Alex,    actually xlsm file will be saved in a temp folder(e.g. 123.xlsm). while retrieving it as http://localhost/temp/123.xlsm. file download dialog appears. while saving it in desktop i want the file to be readonly

Answer (score 3):

It is not possible for an ASP.NET application to assert any control over files on the user's machine. This includes where the file is saved or file permissions/attributes.